# three.js particle system particle cannot move

Tags: javascript, three.js

I read a Chinese book about WebGL. I run the particle system example of the book with firefox, I meet a problem my particle cannot move.

I put my source code and resource in the website:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FBEB6373D9321A7F!649236&authkey=!AA4upPPcARcAvso&ithint=file%2czip

Console Logs on the browser are:

"THREE.WebGLRenderer" "75"

three.min.js:631:0 "THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use THREE.TextureLoader() instead."

three.min.js:791:67 "THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial has been renamed to THREE.PointsMaterial."

three.min.js:777:230 "THREE.ParticleSystem has been renamed to THREE.Points."

three.min.js:769:197 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (109x109). Resized to 128x128"

Here is partial code of the html file:

```
function updateParticles(){

   var particleNum = particleSystem.geometry.vertices.length;

   for(var i=0; i<particleNum; i++){
       particle = particleSystem.geometry.vertices[i];
       particle.z +=  5;       
       if(particle.z>1000){
          particle.z-=2000;
       }
   }
}


function animate() {

   requestAnimationFrame(animate);

   updateParticles();

   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Could someone help to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe using an old version of three.js and it doesn't work with the particle system. [Here](https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/) is a sample that is pretty close to what you are doing. When I run this sample locally it works, then replacing by the three.min.js from your project it stops working. You can grab the three.js version used by this sample [there](https://aerotwist.com/static/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/demo/js/Three.js).

```
  // @see http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
     return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
             window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
             window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
             window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
             window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
             function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
             };
  })();
  // set the scene size
  var WIDTH = 400,
          HEIGHT = 300;

  // set some camera attributes
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
          ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
          NEAR = 0.1,
          FAR = 10000;

  // get the DOM element to attach to
  // - assume we've got jQuery to hand
  var $container = $('#container');

  // create a WebGL renderer, camera
  // and a scene
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  var camera = new THREE.Camera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
          ASPECT,
          NEAR,
          FAR  );
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
  camera.position.z = 300;

  // start the renderer - set the clear colour
  // to a full black
  renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0, 1));
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  // attach the render-supplied DOM element
  $container.append(renderer.domElement);

  // create the particle variables
  var particleCount = 1800,
          particles = new THREE.Geometry(),
          pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
             color: 0xFFFFFF,
             size: 20,
             map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
                     "./Images/icon_ch.png"
             ),
             blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
             transparent: true
          });

  // now create the individual particles
  for(var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {

     // create a particle with random
     // position values, -250 -> 250
     var pX = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
             pY = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
             pZ = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
             particle = new THREE.Vertex(
                     new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ)
             );
     // create a velocity vector
     particle.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
             0,             // x
             -Math.random(),    // y
             0);                // z

     // add it to the geometry
     particles.vertices.push(particle);
  }

  // create the particle system
  var particleSystem = new THREE.ParticleSystem(
          particles,
          pMaterial);

  particleSystem.sortParticles = true;

  // add it to the scene
  scene.addChild(particleSystem);

  // animation loop
  function update() {

     // add some rotation to the system
     particleSystem.rotation.y += 0.01;

     var pCount = particleCount;
     while(pCount--) {
        // get the particle
        var particle = particles.vertices[pCount];

        // check if we need to reset
        if(particle.position.y < -200) {
           particle.position.y = 200;
           particle.velocity.y = 0;
        }

        // update the velocity
        particle.velocity.y -= Math.random() * .1;

        // and the position
        particle.position.addSelf(
                particle.velocity);
     }

     // flag to the particle system that we've
     // changed its vertices. This is the
     // dirty little secret.
     particleSystem.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;

     renderer.render(scene, camera);

     // set up the next call
     requestAnimFrame(update);
  }
  requestAnimFrame(update);
```

Comment: hey hey your solution on revision 40 and his problem on revision 75 (latest). Ouchh